# A z-index layering issue with the numbers in this site's theme

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It's not terribly noticeable, but if you open the achievements tab, a keen-eyed observer might notice that the `1.` in the `Questions` button is not covered up by this panel like the rest of the button.

Here's a picture that shows exactly where to look, in traditional hand draw red lines.

[image: proof]

It appears the `z-index` value of `200` puts it higher up than the panel. If I reduce the `z-index` to `99`, it works properly.

[image: code]

It's not a huge problem, it doesn't look like anyone else has really noticed it or cared to post it to Meta, but it's one of those little things I just can't un-see now.

Comment: Crap, now I won't be able to un-see it...

Comment: Also, all the numbers have the same z-index. I don't think it would clash with anything else, but if you expand the width of the drop-down you will see the same effect as on the "1".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now fixed, it'll be live in one of the next production builds.